# Finding closed contours in a graph

Tags: delphi, graph-theory

I have graph and somehow I need to find all closed contours in graph that doesn't contains any other edges of the graph.

I was searching google but only gives me charts :)

Is there any library or if you know name of such algorithm.

thx

Comment: Try Googling it again with the correct spelling of "contours".

Comment: @unknown: Is this homework?  It's courteous to tag it as such if it is.

Comment: No it was not homework, but real requirement to make user life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply, i think i have solution , e.g. if you move from one node to next connected you can pick next one by measuring angle between edges.

Answer (score 3):

[EFG's](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/MathFunctions/) is a good site for Delphi math related information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the index of: [http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-C-Part-Graph-Pt-5/dp/0201361183](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201361183)

The book is published targetting different programming languages if you care about that.